# Add array in array of arrays

Tags: php

I have a $_SESSION index called "items".
Just like this:

$_SESSION['items'];

When user click to add item I check if $_SESSION['items'] exists. If exists, then insert the item, if not, create and insert. Ok.

So I coded this solution:

```
$newItem = array(
    'id'=>$this->getId(),
    'red'=>$this->getRef()
);

if(isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
    array_push($_SESSION['items'],$newItem);
} else {
    $_SESSION['items'] = $newItem;
}
```

Ok.
The problem is:
If the "else" occurs, the $newItem array is pushed into $_SESSION['items'] with this structure:

```
{
0: {
id: "1",
ref: "0001",
}
}
```

Exactly as I was expecting.
But if the "if" statement occurs, my $_SESSION['item'] looses the new indexes and I get a structure like this:

```
{
0: {
id: "1",
ref: "0001",
},
id: "2",
ref: "0001",
}
```

As you can see, the new item is not set as array...
If I add more itens, the issue affects only the last item added...

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
    array_push($_SESSION['items'],$newItem);
} else {
    $_SESSION['items'] = [];

    array_push($_SESSION['items'], $newItem);
}
```

Now, all the `$newItems` will be pushed in to an actual array.

**Output**

```
array(1) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["ref"]=>
      string(3) "ref"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "id-2"
      ["ref"]=>
      string(5) "ref-2"
    }
  }
}
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/ButteryOrdinaryLines) - Dummy data used

Answer (score 0):

Your array_push here seems to be problem, because when you are pushing the array in $_SESSION[‘items’] it takes $newItem array elements and pushes them in the $_SESSION[‘items’]

If you can do as below then it should work

```
$newItem = array(
'id'=>$this->getId(),
    'red'=>$this->getRef()
);
$_SESSION['items'][]= $newItem;
```